# Avoiding lost layers when using QConsolidate?

Tags: qgis, layers

I want to save all the files in my project and the project file locally on my computer. The files are currently saved on a external hard drive.

I have tried QConsolidate before, and it worked, but this time I get a lot of lost layers when trying to reopen my project from my local disk?

I am using QGIS 2.12 Lyon and my files are *.shp and *.tif.

Comment: Create a new folder in your local computer, copy the entire contents from the external hard drive into the new local folder and then try opening the project. I have used this method countless times for transferring projects from external drives, internet etc. without having to use QConsolidate.

Comment: Well, I have files in several different folders on the external hard drive, and I just want to copy the ones that are included in my project. I want to import as few files as possible to my local disk, and the folders on the external hard drive include very much data that I don't need at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I have the QConsolidate plugin installed on my 2.18.13 version of QGIS. When I run it it saves the .qgs file and also creates a separate folder called "layers" as laid out in the description. To test it I saved in a completely different directory. However, it doesn't always save all the map layers. And when I open the newly saved .qgs file most layers have broken paths. So, I have to "handle bad layers".

I also tried the relocator plugin. It reacts in the same way. The saved layers are broken when I open the relocated .qgs.